# DirectShow transform filter with multiple video frames - Sync with audio

Tags: c#, c++, audio, video, directshow

I've written a DirectShow transform filter (in C# but concept is the same in C++) which buffers multiple video frames before sending them to the renderer (hence a delay). These frames are processed before producing an output frame (think sliding window of say 6 frames).

On a 6fps video source, this causes a 1 second delay. Audio ends up playing back 1 second ahead of video. How do I tell the graph to delay audio by the same amount?

Answer (score 0):

Video and audio renderers present data respecting attached time stamps. You need to restamp your audio data adding the desired delay.

Comment: How do I do that when the audio data isn't under my control? I only have control over the transform filter (and allocator for my downstream).

Comment: You normally do this from audio transform filter. Sample Grabber with SampleCB callback can also do the trick.

Comment: I can't exactly force the user of my transform filter to insert a separate audio transform filter.

Comment: This does not create the full picture of your options, you need to add more details then.